# How to make Eclipse pick up Java 9 options from POM?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, java-9

In my POM, I have some Java 9 specific options for the `maven-compiler-plugin` like

```
<compilerArgs>
    <compilerArg>--add-modules</compilerArg>
    <compilerArg>java.xml.ws.annotation</compilerArg>
</compilerArgs>
```

When importing my project into Eclipse, I'd expect these options to be picked up automatically by the Eclipse compiler, but this is not the case.

Setting the module options manually via Eclipse Build Path Configuration is not really a solution, since these settings do not survive **Maven | Update Project** (Alt+F5).

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.1a. Is this supposed to work at all?

Comment: I believe you're expecting Eclipse to build the project using your `pom.xml` configuration when you import or open a project, which I highly doubt would be the case with any IDE.

Answer (score 1):

JDT has added support for `--add-modules`/`--limit-modules` only recently, so m2e may not yet have picked this up for use in their import project wizard.

Until they had a chance to improve the wizard (and `Update Project` functionality accordingly) modifying the `Build Path` details is indeed your best option.

After you modified the `Contents` of the `JRE System Library` (via node `Is modular`) - does `Alt+F5` really remove your modification? As long as m2e doesn't understand these details, they shouldn't blindly remove it, but for now you may have to refrain from using `Alt+F5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **arg** tag rather than the **compilerArg** tag.

See [this example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) from Apache:

```
<configuration>
  <compilerArgs>
    <arg>-verbose</arg>
    <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
   </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

Presumably your **compilerArg** tags are not recognized, and are just being ignored.

Comment: Both `<compilerArg>` and `<arg>` are fine when running `mvn install` from the commandline. `<arg>` does not solve the problem for Eclipse.